# Where can I find the paper from Maxwell Garnett?

Tags: material-science, specific-reference

I am looking for this paper:

**Maxwell Garnett, J. C., “Colours in metal glasses and metal
films,” Philos. Trans. R. Soc. London, Sect. A, Vol. 3, 385–420,
1904.**

Does anyone know where I can find it. 
Please, before you downvote, I really did search a lot on the internet ! (and yes, I know this site is not dedicated for such questions, but I am sure that I can find the people here who might know where to look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Maxwell%20Garnett%2C%20J.%20C.%2C%20%E2%80%9CColours%20in%20metal%20glasses%20and%20metal%20films%2C%E2%80%9D%20Philos.%20Trans.%20R.%20Soc.%20London%2C%20Sect.%20A%2C%20Vol.%203%2C%20385%E2%80%93420%2C%201904.&btnG=).

That gave me [this link](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rsta.1904.0024).

Comment: Thank you so much!